# How is domain name used for Amazon issued SSL certificates in ACM

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an SSL certificate last night for use with an API (Tomcat, Spring Boot) on AWS Elastic Beanstalk using instructions provided by Amazon Certificate Manager.

When creating the cert, I entered the URL of my static site that calls the API, which is hosted by GoDaddy. ACM sent an email to my URL which I opened and approve and I now see the cert as issued, by Amazon, in my certs. I am also able to select it when I configure HTTPS for my EB load balancer. I am not able to export this cert though as it isn't private.

My question is, how is domain name used? I think I'm a little confused about how to use SSL on both my API and my static site AS WELL as the small bit of static content I'll host out of Tomcat.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ACM certs can only be used with AWS services - Cloudfront (if the cert is issued in us-east-1) and regionally on the classic load balancer and application load balancer.

You cannot export the cert for use in other products, so if you wanted to have Tomcat handle SSL you would need to get either a commercial cert or use something like Let's Encrypt.

If you have multiple host names you want to protect, you have different options.

You can get one cert per hostname if they are running on completely separate infrastructure; you can also have multiple host names in a single cert - even if there are multiple domains; and finally you can get a wildcard cert.

Comment: So if only my domain were with GoDaddy, and all content on AWS, I could use the cert the AWS minted, hence the validation email to admin@my-domain.com? (And from what I'm reading Route53 could be used to integrated my domain and AWS)

Comment: Yes.  You can keep your domain registration with GoDaddy, but point DNS at Route53 (create a zone in Route53, then set the NS and SOA records to the AWS values).  That will allow you to use domain-validated certs.  You can also do this by creating the appropriate TXT values at godaddy.

Comment: After reading more seems Route53 is the way to go for me as GoDaddy doesn't support Lets Encrypt and sells expensive certs. Thanks!